# CRON bash execution result differs from manual launch

Tags: linux, bash, git, cron

I use [GOGS](https://gogs.io/) as a personal Git server (using Docker image). I made a backup script which runs fine when I launch it manually, but when CRON lauches it, seems to malfunction as backups are strictly identical to previous one.

**IMPORTANT PRECISION : *usual problems like this are related to $PATH that might be incomplete, but script below only uses `docker`, `ls`, `head` or `xargs` commands which are under `/usr/bin` or `/usr` (so in `$PATH`).***

Example results  on 3 weeks (CRON once a week) :

```
root@1:~# ll /path/to/backup/
total 1724864
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    588742750 janv. 29 11:30 gogs_2018_01_29.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    588742750 janv. 29 11:30 gogs_2018_02_02.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    588742750 janv. 29 11:30 gogs_2018_02_09.zip
```

Even system dates are **identical**... While date setup by bash are good related on execution. I don't get it.

After manual launch :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    588742750 janv. 29 11:30 gogs_2018_01_29.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    588742750 janv. 29 11:30 gogs_2018_02_02.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    589503781 févr.  9 11:21 gogs_2018_02_09.zip
```

Last backup is bigger, dates matches... Worked.

**Why do I have this malfunction on CRON launch only?**

Script `gogs_backup`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make backup
docker exec -i -t gogs_1 /app/gogs/gogs backup --target /tmp --archive-name gogs.zip

# Build file name
now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
file="/path/to/backup/gogs_$now.zip"

# Copy file
docker cp gogs_1:/tmp/gogs.zip $file

# Remove everything from /tmp dir
docker exec -i -t gogs_1 rm -rf /tmp/gogs*

# Keep only 3 in destination folder
ls -drt /path/to/backup/* | head -n-3 | xargs rm
```

CRON line :

```
0       3       *       *       5       bash /path/to/gogs_backup
```

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

Comment: Interesting link but AFAIS : not `$PATH` problem (even without setting `PATH`, I checked with tip given, `/usr` and `/usr/bin` do the job here, I got a carriage return at the end of my crontab file, got already shebang to force `bash` usage... So far this is only relevant tips I could see to be applied to my problem

Comment: Do you have a logfile, to read crons message? What does it tell you? Can you add error messages to your script, if one of the commands fails, to see where it fails? Can you add something, which proves, that the script is run at all (update a timestamp file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mncl post, I decided to have a look again on docker commands documentation. 
I spotted here that I runned `docker exec -i -t gogs_1 /app/gogs/gogs backup --target /tmp --archive-name gogs.zip`.

`-i` seemed useless to me, as it is a CRON launch. I removed it and the CRON launched script runned well.

Nonetheless, [the Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#options) about `-i` puzzle me out. Why keeping STDIN attached to command would be a problem in this case?

Answer (score 1):

From the exec documentation

```
The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container.
```

And from the cp documentation

```
The CONTAINER can be a running or stopped container.
```

So my guess is that docker exec fails because the container is stoped, but cp works because it works on stoped containers.

Check your logs. And check your return values, there are more bugs in this script.

Comment: Good idea but in my case it's not. Container is live and running while script is running

Comment: Maybe -i made it fail? If so same effect as I wrote, but for a different reason.